# Java Eclipse android syntax errors with anonymous inner class

Tags: java, android, syntax-error, anonymous-inner-class

I am trying to program a sort of 'menu' in android with 3 buttons, and OnClickListeners recording input from each.
However, I am getting some strange syntax errors.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.galaxydefense;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

Button buttonplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);
Button buttonhelp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonhelp);
Button buttoncredits=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttoncredits);
buttonplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread play=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent play=new Intent("android.intent.action.PLAY");
                    startActivity(play);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
buttonhelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread help=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent help=new Intent("android.intent.action.HELP");
                    startActivity(help);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
);
buttoncredits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread credits=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent credits=new Intent("android.intent.action.CREDITS");
                    startActivity(credits);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
);
}
```

I am receiving the following errors:

> line 24 - Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
>
> line 94 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

I am not sure if this error actually is a syntax error or just another error incorrectly diagnosed by the compiler.

Comment: The code seems to be fine. Can you try to clean, and build the project again. Alternatively, close your IDE, and restart it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not write listener out of function. Replace your code with following code :

```
package com.example.galaxydefense;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);
    Button buttonhelp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonhelp);
    Button buttoncredits=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttoncredits);
    buttonplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread play=new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Intent play=new Intent("android.intent.action.PLAY");
                        startActivity(play);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
    buttonhelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread help=new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Intent help=new Intent("android.intent.action.HELP");
                        startActivity(help);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
    );
    buttoncredits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Thread credits=new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Intent credits=new Intent("android.intent.action.CREDITS");
                        startActivity(credits);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
    );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put code directly inside the class as your doing.
Use instead a constructor or an initializer block.

What your doing is define 3 fields in MainActivity : (buttonPlay, buttonHelp, buttonCredits) : This is ok. But then you're not allowed to write code directly as you do.

You can circumvent this behavior by wrapping your code **after** your fields inside an initializer block like this :

```
{ /* This is an initializer block ... */
buttonplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread play=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent play=new Intent("android.intent.action.PLAY");
                    startActivity(play);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
buttonhelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread help=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent help=new Intent("android.intent.action.HELP");
                    startActivity(help);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
);
buttoncredits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread credits=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent credits=new Intent("android.intent.action.CREDITS");
                    startActivity(credits);
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
);
/* Initializer block finishes here */ }
```